# Is it is possible to have Arqade notifications on iPhone?

Tags: support, notifications

Website looks great mobile but I would love to have push notifications when something happens. Is there any way to have that kind of app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only a few Stack Exchange apps for iPhone:

- [SOStacked](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sostacked/id427708024?mt=8)
- [StackWise](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stackwise-stack-overflow-stack/id556308691?mt=8)
- [Six to Eight](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/six-to-eight/id384094708?mt=8)
- [Stack Up](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-up/id383709484?mt=8)
- [Answers for Stack Exchange](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/answers-for-stack-exchange/id488577641?mt=8)

Unfortunately, none of them provide push notifications, and all but StackWise seem to be on development hiatus.

An alternative to a native app, which requires a Mac, is to use [SENotifier](https://stackapps.com/questions/3081/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x), [Growl](http://growl.info) (a third-party notification app for Mac, like Mountain Lion's Notification Center), and the iPhone app [Prowl](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prowl-growl-client/id320876271?mt=8). SENotifier provides Growl notifications for your Stack Exchange inbox and Prowl can convert Growl notifications into push notifications, which would have the end result of creating your own push notification system for Stack Exchange.

Unfortunately, this has a caveat in that Prowl hasn't been updated in over a year, and the recent reviews indicate that it might not work in iOS 6, but it might be worth a shot anyway.